# How to get and store client platform (os and type of browser with versions), device location and date and time

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Backend, started to learn backend with Node.js
Wondering how servers manage to get client details such as client platform (os and type of browser with versions), device location and date and time, IP address and all, to be store in the server for security purpose when a request have been made.

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried yet.

Comment: I just googled to find an answer, but so far didn't find what I was looking for

Comment: @developer-rahul is your issue resolved by using answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the device location in a request unless frontend developer send it from frontend.

you can get these params in the request header => Ip address, user-agent, host, hostname, remoteAddress, pathname, method
e.g.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.headers);
});
```